# How to include 0 value when binning

Tags: python, pandas, bins

Can you please tell me how to include also 0 here?

```
data['count_comma'] = pd.cut(data['comma'], bins=[0,6,np.inf], labels=['lt6','ge6'])
```

Trying as above, I get `NaN` values when I have no comma (i.e., 0) in texts. It should be included and get value `lt6`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `include_lowest=True` argument.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'comma': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

data['count_comma'] = pd.cut(data['comma'], 
                             bins=[0, 6, np.inf], labels=['lt6','ge6'],
                             include_lowest=True)
```

---

```
   comma count_comma
0      0         lt6
1      1         lt6
2      2         lt6
3      3         lt6
4      4         lt6
5      5         lt6
6      6         lt6
7      7         ge6
8      8         ge6
```